# OMA DM implementation in Windows MDM

Tags: windows-phone-8, syncml, oma

In Windows MDM,After completing certificate enrolment stage how to initiate communication between server and mobile using OMA DM?

What to exactly we have to write on server side for initiation?I mean programmatically. How to use CSP's(Configuration service provider).

Like there is synchronization period defined in wap-provisioning-xml which is used for communication between device and server.I have referred WP8_Device_Management Protocol document.I am not getting how to write code on server side which will contain CSP's.

I need help.

Comment: We have some problems in certificates. That's why polling was not happening successfully.Now we recognized bug and all working fine.

Comment: hey any updates on this .. ? m confused too :( struggling to get exact  way to send data for add command for various MOF classes. e.g MDM_Client , MDM_Restrictions etc...